# IEEE journal or conference total number of publications?

Tags: publications, journals, ieee

Pardon me if it is a basic question but I don't seem to get the solution. Is there any way to get total number of IEEE publications for a specific journal. e.g. I would like to know the total number of publications of *IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering* from all of its issues but I don't see any option of that on journal's home page. Is there a way to do it?

I have tried Scopus as well but It does not seem to include all the publications from this specific journal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious: what is it that you want to do with this information?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Journal/27/tse-ieee-transactions-on-software-engineering) addresses your journal of interest, specifically.

More generally, academic.research.microsoft.com can be used to find such information for other journals, as well as conferences.

**Disclaimer:** As user ff524 has pointed out in the comments of this answer, Microsoft Academic Search has stopped indexing/tracking "even a fraction of papers published since 2011", as reported by [this](http://blogs.nature.com/news/2014/05/the-decline-and-fall-of-microsoft-academic-search.html) article. I thank ff524 for pointing this out.

Comment: Microsoft Academic Search has basically [stopped indexing](http://blogs.nature.com/news/2014/05/the-decline-and-fall-of-microsoft-academic-search.html) all but a tiny bit of new content years ago.

Comment: @ff524 Thank you for pointing that out. I had not seen that article and would explain the asymptotic decay in reported publication numbers for the last few years. I will update my answer to include this disclaimer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Before posting this question, I also tried Microsoft Academic but as pointed out, they don't seem to index all the articles. I was wondering if IEEE has that option. I am doing Literature review and I don't want to miss something important because you never know.... So I guess I'll have to do it manually?

Comment: @JewelThief Yeah, that makes it kind of hard. I know of no other sources by which publication counts, by journal, can be obtained, unfortunately. My lit reviews, for what it's worth, usually consist of traversing citations backwards and forwards from the papers that I know of and have been able to find. Maybe a scholar more knowledgable than I has an answer to your definitive quandary. Best of luck!